# MySQL getting the lowest ID for a certain user -or- the ID of the entry with the highest urgency for each row

Tags: mysql

I have the following database

```
id | user | urgency | problem          | solved
```

The information in there has different users, but these users all have multiple entries

```
1  | marco | 0      | MySQL problem    | n
2  | marco | 0      | Email problem    | n
3  | eddy  | 0      | Email problem    | n 
4  | eddy  | 1      | MTV doesn't work | n
5  | frank | 0      | out of coffee    | y
```

What I want to do is this: Normally I would check everybody's oldest problem first. I use this query to get the ID's of the oldest problem.

```
select min(id) from db group by user
```

this gives me a list of the oldest problem ID's. But I want people to be able to make a certain problem more urgent. I want the ID with the highest urgency for each user, or ID of the problem with the highest urgency

Getting the max(urgency) won't give the ID of the problem, it will give me the max urgency.

To be clear: I want to get this as a result

```
row  |   id
0    |   1
1    |   4
```

The last entry should be in the results since it's solved

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ...
From SomeTable As T
    Join    (
            Select T1.User, Min( T1.Id ) As Id
            From SomeTable As T1
                Join    (
                        Select T2.User, Max( T2.Urgency ) As Urgency
                        From SomeTable As T2
                        Where T2.Solved = 'n'
                        Group By T2.User
                        ) As MaxUrgency
                    On MaxUrgency.User = T1.User
                        And MaxUrgency.Urgency = T1.Urgency
            Where T1.Solved = 'n'
            Group By T1.User
            ) As Z
        On Z.User = T.User
                And Z.Id = T.Id
```

Comment: seems to be getting very close to where I'm looking for! Forgot one entry in the database, I only want to get back unsolved problems. I don't know where to put in the "where solved='n'" in this query.

Comment: @patrick - I think you are going to need that filter on the two inner most levels. You need it in the inner most join because otherwise you might get that the solved issue is the most urgent. You need it at the next most inner join because you the lowest id for a given user might be solved. However, on the outer most table since we're joining on Id, it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: the urgency is unique for every user. A user can only prioritize a problem which will set the ugency 1 higher than the highest urgency for that user. When the problem is fixed the urgency is set back to 0. So there's no risk of two problems with the same urgency for the same user...

Comment: @patrick - That is a useful piece of information about the schema that you should mention in your OP. This rule is enforced at the database level or the application level? If the later, then you should still assume that you might get bad data that violates that rule. Regardless, the solution I provided will work whether that rule is enforced or not.

Comment: @Thomas I know I'm late to this thread, but I'm having a similar issue I'm trying to solve in a larger join operation.  To solve the original question, you could leave out the outer most join operation and just return min(T1.Id).  Also, the Z.User = T.User is redundant if T.Id is unique...  Of course, if he needs the actual full data of the rows then the outer join is useful.

Answer (score 0):

The following will get you exactly one row back -- the most urgent, probably oldest problem in your table.

```
select id from my_table where id = (
    select min(id) from my_table where urgency = (
        select max(urgency) from my_table
    )
)
```

I was about to suggest adding a create_date column to your table so that you could get the oldest problem first for those problems of the same urgency level.  But I'm now assuming you're using the lowest ID for that purpose.

But now I see you wanted a list of them.  For that, you'd sort the results by ID:

```
select id from my_table where urgency = (
    select max(urgency) from my_table
) order by id;
```

[Edit:  Left out the order by!]

I forget, honestly, how to get the row number.  Someone on the interwebs suggests something like this, but no idea if it works:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘row', id from my_table where ...
```

Comment: this is not quite what I was looking for. This gives one result back, I need an ID list of everybody, basically a list grouped by user, with the ID of either the oldest problem (indeed checked by ID) or the highest urgency. ID is fine, I don't need the row number

Comment: maybe this helps: every user can see their own list through this query: select * from problem where user='eddy' order by urgency desc, id asc

that will show the user's own list. I'm looking for the top entry on each of these lists. grouping and sorting doesn't work 'cause that will sort the results of the grouping.

Comment: Please re-read the entire post.  I was editing a good bit.  Looks like you read it before I was done.

Comment: Marvo, Kudo's for your great reply, but I still get one row.

Comment: Note that in your sample set in the original post, you only have one row of urgency = 1.

Comment: but I need 1 and 4 in the above sample. So either the oldest from a user or the one with the highest urgency

Comment: I see.  I got thrown by an "or" in your problem description somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of esoteric ways to do this,  but here's one of the clearer ones.

First build a query go get your min id and max urgency:

```
SELECT 
    user,
    MIN(id) AS min_id, 
    MAX(urgency) AS max_urgency
FROM
    db
GROUP BY
    user
```

Then incorporate that as a logical table into
a larger query for your answers:

```
SELECT 
    user,
    min_id,
    max_urgency,
    (    SELECT MIN(id) FROM db
         WHERE user = a.user
             AND urgency = a.max_urgency
    ) AS max_urgency_min_id
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        user,
        MIN(id) AS min_id, 
        MAX(urgency) AS max_urgency
    FROM
        db
    GROUP BY
        user
) AS a
```

Given the obvious indexes, this should be pretty efficient.